# shared_ptr or unique_ptr to CustomDialogEx

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Hell All,

I am creating tab-controls on the fly. For this purpose, i am doing

```
CustomDialogEx *tabPages[TOTAL_MODULES];
```

and in constructor I am doing

```
CModuleTabCtrl::CModuleTabCtrl()
{    
    tabPages[0] = new CPodule;
    tabPages[1] = new CSBModule;
    tabPages[2] = new CPTModule;
    tabPages[3] = new CQSModule;
}
```

and in the init() method, i am doing

```
void CModuleTabCtrl::Init()
{
    // Add Dialog pages to tabPages array.
    tabPages[0]->Create(IDD_DLG_P, this);
    tabPages[1]->Create(IDD_DLG_SB, this);
    tabPages[2]->Create(IDD_DLG_PT, this);
    tabPages[3]->Create(IDD_DLG_QS, this);
}
```

When I tried to use the smart pointers like this

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomDialogEx[TOTAL_MODULES]>tabPages;
```

it is giving error at the place where I am calling the base class member functions.
Example:

```
tabPages[0]->Create(IDD_DLG_P, this);
```

it gives the following error...

```
left of '->Create' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

How do I implement using smart pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a pointer to an array of base-class objects, which isn't what you want. You want an array of pointers, as in your first example:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomDialogEx> tabPages[TOTAL_MODULES];
tabPages[0].reset(new CPodule);        // Create the first object
tabPages[0]->Create(IDD_DLG_P, this);  // Do the weird second-stage initialisation
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::unique_ptr<Type> name[Count];
```

So you have to change your line to:

```
std::unique_ptr<CustomDialogEx> tabPages[TOTAL_MODULES];
```

Use unique_ptr if there is always one obvious owner of an object and
shared_ptr if the object is hold by a group of owners using it.

If you want to know more about the backgrounds, reading this paper might help:

http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf